# Instance of object becoming null in PHP

Tags: php

We have been experience an intermittent issue with variables of instantiated objects seemingly randomly becoming null within a line or two of code.

For example

```
class Club {
}

class Foo {
    public function Bar(Club $club)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

$club = new Club();
(new Foo())->Bar($club);
```

Would through an error `Argument 1 passed to Foo::bar() must be an instance of Club, null given` this has been particularly prevalent when running unit tests but have seen it seen it on occasion occur on live requests.

Have even tried using mockery to circumnavigate any possible issues within the Club class

```
$club = Mockery::mock(Club::class);
(new Foo())->Bar($club);
```

This is running PHP 7.0.12-1 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and PHPUnit 5.4.7

Anybody experienced any similar issues? or any ideas on how to debug such an issue (especially given the intermittent nature of it)

Comment: Is the problem the same if you set an attribute inside `Club` ?
**EDIT**: Using `PHP 7.0.12 (cli)` on Windows 8, the code in your example works fine. Maybe a bug in Ubuntu build.

Comment: No problem using [this online PhP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d4b0907775a7c94422c5d46b4788f41cedcf82f7).

Comment: @AnthonyB yeah, the code here has obviously been simplified. 

One particular unit test uses
`$club = Mockery::mock(Club::class);`
`$club->club_id = 47;`
`$article = ClubNewsUtility::getArticle($club, 12);`   

Hmm can't get the formatting right in the comments but you get the idea

Comment: @JohnHickling I tested it on my machine, I think it's a possible bug of Ubuntu build.

Comment: @AnthonyB cheers will try bumping the Ubuntu version up see if that makes any difference

Comment: @JohnHickling Have you tried to build PHP by yourself ? As seen on Windows and inside the sandbox, your code should work.

Comment: A general issue this might not be. Providing your code unsimplified might help. Maybe your variable nullifies because of `global` you use?

Comment: This simplified code (your example) is also failing on your machine ?